# StorageProvider: What is populating and what does PopulationPolicy do?

Tags: windows-runtime, file-storage

I'm reading up on [Cloud file storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cfapi/build-a-cloud-file-sync-engine), and ran across the `PopulationPolicy` property under `Storage.Provider.StorageProviderSyncRootInfo`, but I'm not sure what this does. The definition that [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.provider.storageproviderpopulationpolicy?view=winrt-22000#definition) provided to just cut off. Under the [Fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.provider.storageproviderpopulationpolicy?view=winrt-22000#fields) section, `AlwaysFull` sounds similar to how the first part of [`HydrationPolicyModifier`'s `ValidationRequired`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.provider.storageproviderhydrationpolicymodifier?view=winrt-22000#remarks) field works ("`it guarantees that the data returned by the sync provider is always persisted to the disk prior to it being returned to the user application`"). I believe that hydration fills the placeholder object with the correct data from the cloud (correct me), but I'm confused about what populate does.

What is populating?
What does changing the `PopulationPolicy` to `Full` and `AlwaysFull` do?

Answer (score 2):

Population is about files and folders (placeholders), not their content (Hydration).

If you don't use `AlwaysFull` (so the only valid value left is `Full`), the platform will call your engine back with [CF_CALLBACK_TYPE_FETCH_PLACEHOLDERS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/ne-cfapi-cf_callback_type), otherwise this type of callback will not be used.

Comment: That makes more sense. Does that mean when I want an up-to-date list of objects, I should use `Full` instead, so that it would call for a sync? `AlwaysFull` sounds a bit counter-intuitive since it assumes that all the files are available. Perhaps this option is supposed to be used for a custom population-check?

Comment: IMHO, using AlwaysFull is the easiest route (OneDrive does that too), you just create regular files and convert them if you want them to be placeholders (CfConvertToPlaceholder).